# How to configure resharper to add comments to C# region blocks?

Tags: resharper

I am working on `Visual Studio 2017` with `Resharper Ultimate 2018.3`

When I write a region block like by type `#region[TAB]`, it generates the following snippet:

```
#region MyRegion



#endregion
```

`MyRegion` is highlighted and I can type to edit it. But I want the following snippet to be generated when I do the above:

```
#region MyRegion



#endregion // MyRegion
```

See the commented part after `#endregion`. How can I do this with resharper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in `Resharper`. Navigate to `Resharper->Tools->Templates Explorer`

Double-click `#region` and it will open `Template #region` in code window of visual studio.
There by default, the code will be:

```
#region $name$
     $SELECTION$$END$
  #endregion
```

Change it to:

```
#region $name$
     $SELECTION$$END$
  #endregion // $name$
```